# Execution gets stuck at date picking functionality of selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium automation, I have written a script to pick check in and check out dates from webpage of tripadvisor.in. I hope the code and xpaths are correct coz out of 7 or 8 executions the scrips successfully running only once. I thought abt synchronization issue and tried adding all types of waits but still the execution getting stuck as calendar. Sometimes stucking at check-in date, sometimes at check-out date but sometimes working fine. Can I get help to sort this issue plz...

```
public void selectCheckDate(String date, WebElement forwardArrow) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        try {
            Date expectedDate = dateFormat.parse(prop.getProperty(date));
            String day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(expectedDate);
            String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(expectedDate);
            String year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(expectedDate);
            String expectedMonthYear = month + " " + year;
            logger.log(Status.INFO, "Expected Month and year: "+expectedMonthYear);
        
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

        String dd1 = "", dd2 = "";
        String d1 = null, d2 = null;
        boolean flag1 = false;
        boolean flag2 = false;
        while (true) {

            String displayDate1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='vr-datepicker-LargeStyles__caption--Srrff']/div")).getText();
            String displayDate2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='vr-datepicker-LargeStyles__caption--Srrff']/div)[2]")).getText();

            if (displayDate1.contains(expectedMonthYear)) {
                //addWait();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
                        d1 = "//*[@id='BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW']/div[14]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div["
                                + i + "]/div[" + j + "]";
                        boolean ex = isElementExists(d1);
                        if(ex==true) {
                            dd1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(d1)).getText();
                            if (dd1.equals(day)) {
                                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(d1))).click();
                                //driver.findElement(By.xpath(d1)).click();
                                flag1 = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (flag1 == true) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag1 == true) {
                    reportPass("Entered date: "+prop.getProperty(date));
                    break;
                }

            } else if (displayDate2.contains(expectedMonthYear)) {
                //addWait();
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
                        d2 = "//*[@id='BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW']/div[14]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div["
                                + i + "]/div[" + j + "]";
                        boolean ex1 = isElementExists(d2);
                        if(ex1==true) {
                            dd2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(d2)).getText();
                            if (dd2.equals(day)) {
                                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(d2))).click();
                                //driver.findElement(By.xpath(d2)).click();
                                flag2 = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                    if (flag2 == true) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag2 == true) {
                    reportPass("Entered date: "+prop.getProperty(date));
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                forwardArrow.click();
            }

        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        reportFail(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share DOM  of calender elements?

Comment: both checkin and checkout date elements